# pass event handler to UserControl for assignment to dynamic LinkButton

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a public function in a UserControl that takes an EventHandler parameter and assigns it to a bunch of LinkButtons created at run time. The function being passed in the EventHandler is located on the form with the UserControl. A breakpoint defined in the callback function is not being reached, so I figured I'm doing something wrong.

**Default.aspx**

```
<uc1:tcControl runat="server" ID="tc1" />
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
tcControl1.ShowTags(new EventHandler(ClickHandler));
```

and

```
void ClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

**tcControl.ascx.cs**

```
public void ShowTags(EventHandler handlerCallback)
```

and

```
LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
lb.ID = t.Name.Replace(" ", "_");
lb.Text = t.Name.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
lb.Click += handlerCallback;
```

Comment: I'm not reattaching the handlers on postback. Do I need to rebuild the UserControl? The dynamic LinkButtons survive the postback how would I re-attach their handlers? I guess I've answered a question that got deleted...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should expose a public event in your User Control that the parent page can subscribe to.

From http://www.marten-online.com/csharp/simple-custom-event-handling.html:

```
  public delegate void LinkButtonClickHandler (object sender,  EventArgs data);

  // The event
  public event LinkButtonClickHandler LinkButtonClicked;

  // The method which fires the Event
  protected void OnLinkButtonClick (object sender,  EventArgs data)
  {
      // Check if there are any Subscribers
      if (LinkButtonClicked!= null)
      {
          // Call the Event
          LinkButtonClicked(this, data);
      }
  }
```

Now, on your parent page, you can subscribe to this event in your Page_Load event:

```
public void Page_Load()
{
    userControl.LinkButtonClicked += HandleUserControlLinkButtonClicked;
}

private void HandleUserControlLinkButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs data)
{
    // Handle the click as you wish
}
```

Comment: Note that with event handlers, you need to resubscribe on each PostBack, so the subscription logic is **not** wrapped in an `IsPostBack` check.